# Explicación de como funciona el do while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, while

Acabo de empezar con JS. Es una pregunta super tonta seguro, pero en este ejemplo ¿por qué funciona así?

Según tengo entendido, el `do-while` ejecuta el código al menos una vez antes de chequear si es `true`, por eso sale el prompt, luego MIENTRAS sea `true` se repite el proceso todo el tiempo. PERO yo al cancelar o darle a *Ok* debería ser `false` ya que *Cancel* es `null` y *Ok* es `''` que también es `false`, ¿entonces por qué se repite el proceso siempre?

Si *yourName* es todo menos `null`, `''`, `0` debe ser `true`, pero con `!` será `false`, o sea «*mientras sea `false`, haz `console.log()`*», pero al poner un nombre es `true` (ya que no es una empty string) y me da el nombre igual...

Seguro que es una tonteria o lo estoy pensando del revés.

```js
do {
  var yourName = prompt("Who are you?");
} while (!yourName){
  console.log(yourName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Este ciclo implica que valida la condición después de ejecutar al menos una vez el ciclo, normalmente se usa para eso mismo, ejecutar un fragmento del codigo al menos una vez.

Answer (score 0):

En tu ejemplo, si cancelas, el valor será `null`.
Si le das a aceptar sin escribir nada será `''`.

En ambos casos `yourName` será un valor `falseable`, y si lo negamos será `true` (`!yourName`). Por tanto la expresión del while se evaluará a true y te mostrará otra vez el prompt.

El ejemplo que muestras es equivalente a lo siguiente:

```js
var yourName;

while(!yourName) {
  yourName = prompt('Escribe Nombre')
}

console.log(yourName);
```

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de cancelar, la respuesta es `''`, o sea una cadena vacía.
Javascript hace una validación bastante curiosa cuando se trata de aplicar lógica booleana:

- Si el valor a evaluar es cadena, siempre retornará `true`, aún si es una cadena vacía.
- Si el valor a evalular es un número, evaluará si es distinto a 0, en cuyo caso devolverá `true` (incluso con números negativos). El único número que devolverá `false` es 0.
- Si la variable a evaluar es un arreglo, siempre devolverá `true` aún si está vacío (`[]`).

Para el caso del `prompt`, deberías evaluar usando [el truco de la doble negación](http://deckerix.com/blog/el-truco-de-la-doble-negacion-en-javascript/) de la cadena:

```js
do {
  var yourName = prompt("Who are you?");
  console.log(yourName);
} while (!!yourName);
```

Además, el ciclo `do-while` evalúa la condición *después* de ejecutar el código, no tomará en cuenta lo que escribas entre llaves después del `while` (y este debe ser seguido por un `;`).

Comment: En el caso de cancelar dara null que es false, '' es string vacio y false tambien, y al poner ! lo convierto en true, por eso el loop siempre se repite. Si es cadena vacia no retorna true, retorna false, por eso luego con ! lo convierto en true... no?

Comment: que sentido poner doble negacion, para eso solo pongo yourName y ya. igual no tiene sentido hacer esto ya que sentido tendria que el prompt aparezca hasta que se introduca un dato real

Comment: @fran ¿Cuál es el escenario? ¿en qué caso debe repetirse el ciclo? ¿cuáles son tus condiciones?